# Match X or Y in grep regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, shell, for-loop, sh

I'm trying to run a fairly simple regular expression to clear out some home directories. For background: I'm trying to ask users on my system to clear out their unnecessary files to clear up space on their home directories, so I want to inform users with scripts such as Anaconda / Miniconda installation scripts that they can clear that out.

To generate a list of users who might need such an email, I'm trying to run a simple regular expression to list all homedirs that contain such an installation script. So my assumption would be that the follwing should suffice:

```
for d in $(ls -d /home/); do
    if $(ls $d | grep -q "(Ana|Mini)conda[23].*\.sh"); then
        echo $d;
    fi;
done;
```

But after running this, it resulted in nothing at all, sadly. After a while looking, I noticed that `grep` does not interpret regular expressions as I would expect it to. The following:

```
echo "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" | grep "(Lorem|Ipsum) ipsum"
```

results in no matches at all. Which would then explain why the above forloop wouldn't work either.

My question then is: is it possible to match the specified regular expression `(Ana|Mini)conda[23].*\.sh`, in the same way it matches strings in https://regex101.com/r/yxN61p/1? Or is there some other way to find all users who have such a file in their homedir using a simple for-loop in bash?

Comment: Note that you are probably reinventing the ```find``` command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: grep defaults to Basic Regular Expressions (BRE), but unescaped `()` and `|` are part of Extended Regular Expressions (ERE). GNU grep, as an extension, supports alternation (which isn't technically part of BRE), but you have to escape `\`:

```sh
grep -q "\(Ana\|Mini\)conda[23].*\.sh"
```

Or you can indicate that you want to use ERE:

```sh
grep -Eq "(Ana|Mini)conda[23].*\.sh"
```

Longer answer: this all being said, you don't need grep, and parsing the output of `ls` comes with a lot of [pitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Instead, you can use globs:

```sh
printf '%s\n' /home/*/*{Ana,Mini}conda[23]*.sh
```

should do it, if I understand the intention correctly.

This uses the fact that `printf` just repeats its formatting string if supplied with more parameters than formatting directives, printing each file on a separate line.

`/home/*/*{Ana,Mini}conda[23]*.sh` uses [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion), i.e., it first expands to

```sh
/home/*/*Anaconda[23]*.sh /home/*/*Miniconda[23]*.sh
```

and each of those is then expanded with [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion). `[23]` works the same way as in a regular expression; `*` is "zero or more of any character except `/`".

If you don't know how deep in the directory tree the files you're looking for are, you could use [globstar](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) and `**`:

```sh
shopt -s globstar
printf '%s\n' /home/**/*{Ana,Mini}conda[23]*.sh
```

`**` matches all files and zero or more subdirectories.

Finally, if you want to handle the case where nothing matches, you could set either `shopt -s nullglob` (expand to nothing if nothing matches) or `shopt -s failglob` (error if nothing matches).

Shell patterns are described [here](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching).

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer! I've never seen the use of printf in that way, is there anywhere I can read up on more details about globs?

Comment: @Joeytje50 I'll add a few references.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `ls` or `grep` at all for this:

```
shopt -s extglob

for f in /home/*/@(Ana|Mini)conda[23].*.sh; do
  echo "$f"
done
```

With `extglob` enabled, `@(Ana|Mini)` matches either `Ana` or `Mini`.